# Common legend for mutliple pie charts

Tags: matlab, legend, subplot

I have two pie charts, both containing 5 elements. I have separated them with `subplot` command. Now, I want to construct a common legend for these 5 elements.

```
X=[0.3200   0.3800  0.2400  0.0600  0.0001];
Y=[0.14     0.28    0.37    0.11    0.11];

figure
subplot(1,2,1)
H1 = pie(X);
title('Pre-event Distribution', 'FontSize',12)

subplot(1,2,2)
H2 = pie(Y);
title('Post-event Distribution', 'FontSize',12)

L = {'Max','Sym','Dvd','Att','Sta'};

legend([H1, H2],L,'location','southoutside')
```

I wanted to benefit from other similar threads but in those cases they use one legend element corresponding to each subplot. In my case the number of legend elements are not equal to the number of subplots. So, it produces an error:

> One or more of the specified objects can not be included in a legend.

What should I do?

Edit: The subplots use the same colors and I need the legend centered between those subplots.

Comment: The legend is always attached to one axes (i.e. one subplot). If the two subplots use the same colors (as is your case) you can simply add a legend to one of them. Try simply `legend(L)`.

Comment: I tried that one but that I need the legend centered between the subplots. Maybe I'll use a picture editing software.

Answer (score 2):

The legend is always attached to an axes, you cannot create (as far as I know) a legend that references objects in two different axes. But because in your figure both plots use the same colors, you can simply create a legend for one of them, and position it within your figure where you want it:

```
h = legend(L);
sz = h.Position(3:4);
h.Position = [ 0.5-sz(1)/2, 1-sz(2)-0.05, sz ];
```

Note: position units are normalized, such that 0 is the left or bottom edge, and 1 is the right or top edge. The Position vector is `[ left, right, width, height ]`.

I first obtained the size of the legend box, then placed it centered horizontally, and at a distance of 0.05 from the top edge.

You can also select the mouse cursor button in the figure's toolbar, which enables mouse interaction with the components of the figure. Now you can click and drag the legend box to where you want it. `h.Position` now gives you the position back, so you can store this in your program to recreate that same manual location every time you re-create your figure. For example, I dragged the box to this location, which looks good on my screen at least:

```
h.Position = [0.4647, 0.2333, 0.1062, 0.1452];
```

(But note that your box might be of a different size, depending on font sizes and so on.)

---

I think it is better to add the labels directly on the pie chart, rather than have the reader look up colors in a legend. IMO, the exact percentages should never be shown on a figure. If you need to convey exact values, use a table. A figure is to allow to easily compare magnitudes. If you add the percentages, people will focus on those, and ignore the graphical representation. I would present the data like this:

```
X = [0.3200   0.3800  0.2400  0.0600  0.0001];
Y = [0.14     0.28    0.37    0.11    0.11];
L = {'Max','Sym','Dvd','Att','Sta'};

figure
subplot(1,2,1)
pie(X,L);
title('Pre-event Distribution', 'FontSize',12)

subplot(1,2,2)
pie(Y,L);
title('Post-event Distribution', 'FontSize',12)
```